# Find $L=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^8}.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $L=\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^8}.$ Then

1. $L<1$
2. $L>1$
3. $L<\frac{\pi}{4}$
4. $L>\frac{\pi}{4}$.

The given given function is Reimann integrable on [0,1]. I just made a change of variable $t=x^4$, but i cannot get any relation. Help me!

Comment: Don't try to integrate, it's quite complicated in this case. Instead, make up estimates. For answering 1/2, compare $1+x^8$ with $1$. What might you compare to for 3/4?

Comment: @Ian nice of you to set π=3. Makes math "easier".

Comment: @orion Not sure that's what he did. I cannot see it at least. I think he means "options 3 and 4" by "3/4".

Comment: @Scounged It was a joke, actually :) His hint actually hits the point of this question very well.

Answer (score 7):

Since $\frac{1}{1+x^8}< 1$ for all $x\in(0,1)$, we see that $L<1$, and since $$ \frac{1}{1+x^8}>\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ for all $x\in(0,1)$, as $x^8<x^2$ on that range, we see that $$L>\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx =\frac{\pi}{4},$$ and so options $1$ and $4$ apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Taylor series expansion of the given function to attain the result that it approximates to $\frac{8}{9}$ with the error $\frac{1}{17}$. Since $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is smaller than $0.8, L$ is bigger than $\frac{\pi}{4}$, as it is bigger than $0.8$.

The answer given by Eric is much more elegant, however :)